# programmatically exporting dynamic php site to static html?

Tags: php, html, caching, export

I've got a small company site with ~20 "pages", all of which are generated via index.php and templates.

I need to send it to my customer for approval, and he needs to be able to email it to others in his company for viewing in situations where there might not be internet access, such as off a USB stick on an airplane.

I assume there is a nifty way to "save" this site and all its pages to just regular ol' html + images + CSS? Is PHP Caching what I'm looking for or is there a better way?

Note that the site is not online. It exists only on my local dev (and in DVCS...)

Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to make things more complicated.

Just send a link to a website + zip file with bunch of screenshots for those who don't have internet access at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a package consisting of XAMPP and your site, so PHP could work being bundled on USB Flash, for instance. You can, of course, use such tools as WebCopier and Teleport Pro to save your site to static html+css+js+images, but the site won't be a dynamic one, i.e. the guestbook won't accept any messages.